# Splitting front-end and backend

Tags: ee2, ee5, server

Is it possible to split the frontend from the backend and host them on separate servers, for expressionengine?

Comment: Funny, we actually just started discussing that at office, and I may even be throwing together a proof of principal attempt. Our conclusion is that it is likely possible, but does come with some debt in getting it set up. It can also be a bit messy when it comes to how things like cache is handled. But we think it can be done. I'll report back if I put together a functioning test.

Comment: That would be great. I will report back my findings and results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could. The thing you'll need to watch is how you handle/serve URL's and assets (img/files) as your CP domain will likely be different to your front-end website domain. Just bear that in mind when populating the front-end.